# How to turn off smooth scrolling in KDE4

Tags: kde, appearance

I want to turn off smooth scrolling in KDE4 applications. By smooth scrolling, I mean the visual effect that causes the contents of a scrollable area to shift a bit at a time when I scroll with <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>: I want the transition between one page and the previous/next to be instantaneous.

I'm running KDE 4.4.5 on Debian right this minute and my test application is the help browser, but I'd prefer a method that works accross all versions on all systems. I didn't find anything in the System Settings application (of course, there are a lot of them, so I might just not have found the right tab). I switched Appearance/Style/Fine_Tuning/Graphical_effects to “high display resolution and low CPU” but it didn't help. If smooth scrolling is part of some other larger collection of visual effects that I'd have to turn off all at once, I probably won't mind.

Comment: It seems to differ from one widget to another, and perhaps may be specific to the help browser. I see the smooth scrolling when I open the help browser, but not in Kate, Dolphin, or Okular (and I'm pretty sure I haven't configured it away).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smooth scrolling is a feature of the Qt widget set, not of KDE.  There's no system-wide setting that turns it on or off, and disabling it requires changing the problem code.  Sorry.

Comment: [“QScrollArea, which inherits QAbstractScrollArea, provides smooth scrolling for any QWidget (…) You only need to subclass QAbstractScrollArea if you need more specialized behavior (e.g.) if you do not want smooth scrolling.”](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html) Dammit. Hmmm, `LD_PRELOAD`?